# VECM lag length

Tags: time-series, lags, vector-error-correction-model

If I have data on ten stock market indices, each with 1025 observations. Would it be alright to run a VECM(5) that estimates around 520 coefficients/constants? The LR statistic suggests a VECM(5) while the others recommend VECM(2). However, the VECM(5) specification seems to be giving the most stable representations and satisfies the tests for autocorrelation and normality of residuals etc.

Please advise.

Comment: There have been so many questions on lag length selection before, you could certainly benefit from checking them out. Try tags [tag:lags] and [tag:var] or [tag:vecm]. Also, what do you mean by *the others*? (A note for myself: probably it's time to write a canonical answer we could always refer to.)